# How to add Images into Header and footer in pdf with PHPEXCEL

Tags: php, phpexcel

I search this question on Google and also get some results but problem is It does not display any images in header, here is my code

```
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getHeaderFooter()->setOddHeader('&C&H TITLE OF PDF');
$objDrawing = new PHPExcel_Worksheet_HeaderFooterDrawing();
$objDrawing->setName('Logo');
$objDrawing->setDescription('Logo');
$objDrawing->setPath($DOC_ROOT.LOGO);
$objDrawing->setHeight(300);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getHeaderFooter()->addImage($objDrawing, PHPExcel_Worksheet_HeaderFooter::IMAGE_HEADER_LEFT);
```

Comment: Header/Footer are only supported for the Excel5 and Excel2007 Writers

Comment: How can I add header and footer?

Comment: You'd need to write some code to modify the PDF Writer